# Any versions available for Email Templates in sfdc

Tags: apex, community, email-template, versioning

Hi Friends i thought it is not an important question.I went to an interview few days back they ask me about version using in email templates.

But,till no i didn't see any version for email templates in sfdc. They are saying email templates also have version number like apex classes.

Did anyone know any versions available for email templates.If there where to find the version for email templates.Please don't put down vote this question if i had ask anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

See this Help document: [Managing Version Settings for Visualforce Email Templates](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_visualforce_version_settings.htm).

> To aid backwards-compatibility, each Visualforce email template is saved with version settings for the specified version of Visualforce and the API. If the Visualforce email template references installed managed packages, the version settings for each managed package referenced by the Visualforce component are saved too. This ensures that as Visualforce, the API and the components in managed packages evolve in subsequent versions, a Visualforce email template is still bound to versions with specific, known behavior.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev so for other type of email templates doesn't have a version right.